# Convert FALSE rows into TRUE depending on length of consecutive FALSE values in R

Tags: r

I used the following code to detect events based on a criteria, but I would like to change FALSE events to TRUE if there are less than 10 consecutive "Falses", as well as the id counter to keep the last value.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Event = V1 > 20, id = rleid(Event))

Time        V1      Event   id  
20:15:57    26.41   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    25.10   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    23.74   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    22.45   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    21.33   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    20.45   TRUE    6   
20:15:58    19.88   FALSE   7   
20:15:58    19.66   FALSE   7   
20:15:58    19.83   FALSE   7   
20:15:58    20.39   TRUE    8
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
Time        V1      Event   id  
20:15:57    26.41   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    25.10   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    23.74   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    22.45   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    21.33   TRUE    6   
20:15:57    20.45   TRUE    6   
20:15:58    19.88   TRUE    6   
20:15:58    19.66   TRUE    6   
20:15:58    19.83   TRUE    6   
20:15:58    20.39   TRUE    6
```

Note the last id value, that was 8, is now 6, because it is part of the previous event.

For example, if there is a "group" of 12 consecutive FALSEs, all of them should remain FALSE, but if there is a "group" of only 3 FALSEs, all of them should be turned into TRUE.

I hope I made myself clear, and maybe the problem is in the code I am using at the beginning.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I want to consider separate TRUE events that have short "FALSE" events in between as the same event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate `group_id` and use `n()` to get the size of each group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = c(T, T, T, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    group_id = cumsum(x != lag(x, default = 0))
  ) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(x = x | n() < 10)
#> # A tibble: 19 x 2
#> # Groups:   group_id [5]
#>    x     group_id
#>    <lgl>    <int>
#>  1 TRUE         1
#>  2 TRUE         1
#>  3 TRUE         1
#>  4 TRUE         2
#>  5 TRUE         2
#>  6 TRUE         2
#>  7 TRUE         3
#>  8 FALSE        4
#>  9 FALSE        4
#> 10 FALSE        4
#> 11 FALSE        4
#> 12 FALSE        4
#> 13 FALSE        4
#> 14 FALSE        4
#> 15 FALSE        4
#> 16 FALSE        4
#> 17 FALSE        4
#> 18 FALSE        4
#> 19 TRUE         5
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for, I need FALSEs to be considered as a "group", in your code it works like a rolling, if there are 12 consecutive falses, 10 of them are going to be turned into TRUE, but I want if there is a "group" of 12 consecutive FALSEs, all of them should remain FALSE, but if there is a "group" of only 3 FALSEs, all of them should be turned into TRUE. I don't know if it is more helpful. Sorry my first explanation, and thanks for your help!

Comment: @David I've updated my answer based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work with your data:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(Event = V1 > 20) %>% mutate(id = rep(rle(Event)$lengths, rle(Event)$lengths)) %>% group_by(Event) %>% 
+   mutate(Event = case_when(Event == FALSE & n() <= 10 ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ TRUE)) %>% mutate(id = max(id))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Event [1]
   Time        V1 Event    id
   <time>   <dbl> <lgl> <int>
 1 20:15:57  26.4 TRUE      6
 2 20:15:57  25.1 TRUE      6
 3 20:15:57  23.7 TRUE      6
 4 20:15:57  22.4 TRUE      6
 5 20:15:57  21.3 TRUE      6
 6 20:15:57  20.4 TRUE      6
 7 20:15:58  19.9 TRUE      6
 8 20:15:58  19.7 TRUE      6
 9 20:15:58  19.8 TRUE      6
10 20:15:58  20.4 TRUE      6
>
```

Comment: No, sorry... I get all events True, and same id for all. In my data there are falses that should be kept, because there are more than 10 consecutive false values. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: OK, because in your expected answer, FALSE were changed to TRUE, my code tried to replicate that. How would you want your output to be?

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, I didn't wanted the hole column changes, for example, if there is a "group" of 12 consecutive FALSEs, all of them should remain FALSE, but if there is a "group" of only 3 FALSEs, all of them should be turned into TRUE. Hope I made it clear now, sorry again..